# Letter Counter Using Array

Tags: java, counter

I am working on a lab for my cs 1 class and am getting confused on how to write this code. The assignment is to make a code using arrays to count the letters from a string that is inputted by the user. I have looked at other questions very similar to mine but the solution often includes using 'HashMap' which I have not learned yet. I also need to use ASCII characters to help count.

The specific instructions can be found here under problem b:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0BS8YbiOmdecWlEWlh4T1RocDg/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for your time!

Here is what I have so far, all in my main method:

```
System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
    String a = input.nextLine();
    int[] myArray = new int[256];

    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        if((a.charAt(i) == 'a') || (a.charAt(i) == 'A'))
        {
             count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: So what does this code do? any errors? also I dont understand the point of the `myArray` variable.

Comment: You could use the ASCII code of the character as index in the array and at that index store the number of occurrences of that specific character.

Comment: @JackWilliams It outputs a lot of 0s and 1s for the counts im assuming. And im not really what the point of the 'myArray' variable is honestly. I think I got it from looking at similar codes online

Comment: @hotzst How would I go about doing that? Sorry Im still pretty new to this.

Comment: Start by renaming (naming is the single most important activity in programming) `myArray` to `countOfEachEnglishLetter`.

Comment: @TomBlodget Ok! does that really change anything though?

Comment: Now, does `for (int i=0; i < countOfEachEnglishLetter.length; i++)` make sense with `a.charAt(i)`? Maybe you should rename `i`, too. Also, you should read your [requirements specification](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0BS8YbiOmdecWlEWlh4T1RocDg/view?usp=sharing) again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to help you without doing all your homework

- you go through myArray to count something, why not go through the input (you named `a`)

in these lines :

```
for (int i=0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
```

how could you go through the `a` instead of myArray ?

- Can you use myArray to store the count of each kind of character ?

for example `myArray[25]++;` increase by two the count of the 25th character `ascii_value`

- you can use myinteger = (int)mycharacter to convert a character to an integer suitable for indexing an array

for example `int ascii_value = (int)a.charAt(3);` would store the ascii value of the third character of in `ascii_value`. how to store the ascii value of the ith character ?

Comment: Ok, I am not really sure how to do any of those things honestly.

Comment: @Adam7397 I added some hints. Is it enough ?